# A little baking recipe

Tags: riddle

My first question on Puzzling.SE, I don't think it should be too hard.

> Take a bowl and add one.
>   Now add seven.
>   At last mix it all together and bake it at 270 degrees.

What will you get?

Comment: A pan with 8 sticks of melted butter?

Comment: I am not a native English Speaker and i Accidently used the wrong Word

Comment: I have edited the question a little to make it easier to read. If my edit has changed the intent of the question, feel free to rollback the edits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Infinity

Because the riddle bakes down to

> 0 (bowl) + 1 + 7 = 8 which, when rotated 270 degrees, looks like $\infty$

Comment: Correct :) It is an easy riddle but i like it

Comment: Why do you consider the bowl to be 0?

Comment: @Jashaszun - I just looked at this puzzle and immediately knew that the bowl was zero. It is the circular  shape of the bowl together with 'add one' that made me think of zero plus one.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK That was exactly my thought process, too.